# Performant read uint12 binary from file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, binary

I need to read a binary blob from file into a JavaScript array. The blob is little endian, uint 12 bit, I.e.

```
---------------------------------
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
|-------------------------------|
|         data1[7:0]            |
|-------------------------------|
| data2[3:0]    | data1[11:8]   |
|-------------------------------|
|           data2[11:4]         |
---------------------------------
```

It seems like [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) and [bit shifting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp) might be the best way (that's how I solved in Python), but I'm trying to make this very performant (10's of MB in sub-second time scale)

And I'm just testing app performance using the browser tools

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what code you've tried and how you're testing performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW, took me some time to figure out this one... ended up having to use Webassembly, here's the code for others in case someone else wants to do it:

**parse12bit.c**

```
#include <stdint.h>

__attribute__((used)) void parse12bit(unsigned char *buffer, int num_bytes, uint16_t *data)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  do
  {
    data[j] = buffer[i] + ((buffer[i + 1] & 0xF) << 8);
    data[j + 1] = ((buffer[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4) + (buffer[i + 2] << 4);
    i = i + 3;
    j = j + 2;
  } while (i < num_bytes);
}
```

**build.sh** (Installed emcc on mac using `brew install emscripten`)

```
emcc ./parse12bit.c \
  --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm \
  --optimize=3 \
  -nostdlib \
  -Wl,--export-all \
  -Wl,--no-entry \
  -Wl,--allow-undefined \
  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
  -o parse12bit.wasm
```

**parseData.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

interface Parse12bit extends Function {
  // passing location of pointer (first element of array), respects C convention
  (buffer: number, length: number, data: number): void;
}

export const parseDataC = async (bufferArray: Uint8Array) => {
  // Load the wasm into a buffer.
  const wasmBuf = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, `/wasm/parse12bit.wasm`)
  );

  // Make an instance.
  const res = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuf, {});

  // Get function.
  const parse12bit = res.instance.exports.parse12bit as Parse12bit;
  const memory = res.instance.exports.memory as WebAssembly.Memory;

  // calculate total size of shared memory
  const totalBytes =
    bufferArray.length * Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT +
    1 * Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT +
    (bufferArray.length * Uint16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 8) / 12;

  // grow memory if necessary, default created memory not large enough in original implementaiton
  // memory is grown in 64 KiB chunks
  if (memory.buffer.byteLength < totalBytes) {
    memory.grow(Math.ceil((totalBytes - memory.buffer.byteLength) / 65536));
  }

  // Create the input arrays.
  let offset = 0;
  const buffer = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, offset, bufferArray.length);
  buffer.set(Uint8Array.from(bufferArray));

  offset += buffer.length * Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  const numBytes = new Int32Array(memory.buffer, offset, 1);
  numBytes.set([bufferArray.length]);

  offset += Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  const data = new Uint16Array(
    memory.buffer,
    offset,
    (bufferArray.length * 8) / 12
  ); // data in 12 bit at end

  // Call the function.
  parse12bit(buffer.byteOffset, numBytes.byteOffset, data.byteOffset);

  // // Show the results.
  console.log(data);
};
```

Note, the final was from [this very helpful blog post](https://rob-blackbourn.github.io/blog/webassembly/wasm/array/arrays/javascript/c/2020/06/07/wasm-arrays.html)