# Tensorflow or array based bitwise OR/AND in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tensorflow, bitwise-operators

It seems the python implementation of TensorFlow has [bitwise_or implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bitwise/bitwise_or), however, the [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/) does not.

I need to compare two 1D tensors and perform a bitwise OR operation (element-wise). Does anyone now how to do this without looping in javascript (it needs to be done on arrays of lengths in the hundreds of millions, hence avoiding loops)? I've only found [very complicated workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199702/12728698) thus far...

Here's what it looks like in Python with numpy for reference:

```
array_or = array_1 | array_2
```

Comment: Do you assume, that just because you don't have to spell out the looping, python doesn't have to iterate over the two lists? You don't get around it.

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but Python is written on top of C and the libraries are optimized for large vector computations

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: for large arrays and performant code, [I used WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65758597/12728698)

Well, I have something, going to test the performance but it seems like [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) does have the functionality necessary

Turns the following python code

```
out = array1 | ((array2 << 8) & 0xF)
```

into the following javascript code

```
const out = math.bitOr(
  array1,
  math.bitAnd(math.leftShift(array2, 8), 15)
);
```

Comment: I'd have to look into the source of that library, but such libraries usually try to be convenient, flexible, suitable for different use-cases and programming styles. And such flexibility always comes at the cost of performance. Performance wise, a simple loop may be your best option in JS.

Answer (score 0):

> mathjs ... into the following javascript code...

In plain JS you won't get any code more performant than:

```
const length = Math.min(array_1.length, array_2.length);
const array_or = new Int32Array(length);

for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  array_or[i] = array_1[i] | array_2[i];
}
```

> but Python is written on top of C

so are modern JS engines

> and the libraries are optimized for large vector computations

that's not the case in JS. JS wasn't the platform to do such math-heavy operations.

You can't even overload operators like you'd need for something like `object operator object` to work. In JS `array_1 | array_2` would be performed as `Number(String(array_1)) | Number(String(array_2))`.

And the iterator interface in JS is still several times slower than a simple loop over an array.

You may be able to get better performance by doing your math in [wasm](/questions/tagged/wasm), but I have no experience in how big the overhead is to "move" the data back and forth between JS and wasm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ended up going down the rabbit hole of web assembly and it paid off massively in terms of read spedd (but took me a day to figure out how to do it!) ultimately led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65758597/12728698